# Calculate resistors for LED

Tags: arduino, led, resistors

I bought some bead LEDs with these specs.:

- Voltage: DC 3.4~3.6V
- Power: 3W
- Light Color : Cool White
- Electric current: 350-600MA

I have an Arduino powered by a 9V battery. I'd like to connect 10 LED to the Arduino's Digital Pins (4-13) and I'd like to know what type of resistors to use.

Thanks

Comment: uh, what kind of 9V battery? Even at the 1-2W per LED that the "electric current" rating represents, you won't power even one of those LEDs from a PP3 ... at all ... let alone 10.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I use this cuboid battery and I have lighted up one LED through Arduino Uno's 3.3V pin...but for more LED probably i would need a different type of battery.

Comment: Then you have probably lit the LED at a much lower current - and brightness - than its rating allows.

Answer (score 5):

> I'd like to connect 10 LED to the Arduino's Digital Pins

You can't.

The Arduino has an absolute maximum of 40mA from a digital IO pin, and a recommended maximum of 25mA from a digital IO pin.

You can't get 350-600mA out of that.

For those LEDs you need either a decent transistor to switch them, along with a suitable high power resistor with good temperature coefficient, or a proper LED driver, such as the CAT4101 or similar.

You also need a power source capable of providing many amps to drive them all.  At full brightness, 10 LEDs at 600mA would need 6A.

Comment: For reference, here are the current limitations of Arduino pins: http://arduino-info.wikispaces.com/ArduinoPinCurrent